# How to change the default printer in evince?

Tags: printing, evince

I have several printers listed in evince. I was wondering how to change the default printer in evince? Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default printer can be set through the System/Administration/Printing. Give it a try, set your default printer and re-start evince in order to gather the appropiate default printer where to send your stuff.

Good luck!

Comment: Despite what you set for the paper type, it might be still incorrect, depending on your locales. So you should also check the locales, e.g. in `/etc/environment.`